# How do I create an animation for each v-card

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can i make each animation individual and specific to the selected v-card. Currently if one is clicked, all of them play the animation.

```js
data: () => ({
    show: true,
    images: [
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png'), title: 'hello'},
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png')},
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png')},
      
    ],
```

```html
<v-card  class="ms-8 mb-5" v-for="image in images" v-bind:key="image" width="300" height="300" style="display: inline-flex" elevation="15" v-on:click="show = !show">
      <v-img v-if="show" height="300" width="300"
             :src="image.url">
             </v-img>
    </v-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have only one `show`, so if it will be true - all your images would be visible because they all use the same variable. To fix that, you need to create `show` variable into all your objects. Or you can create a component, for example, `image`, and give him `show` like a `props`.  In this case every image is an instance of a component, and all properties will be unique.

```
data: () => ({
    show: true,
    images: [
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png'), title: 'hello', show:true},
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png'),show:true},
      {url:require('@/assets/london.png'), show:true},

    ],

<v-card  class="ms-8 mb-5" v-for="image in images" v-bind:key="image" width="300" height="300" style="display: inline-flex" elevation="15" v-on:click="image.show = !image .show">
      <v-img v-if="image.show" height="300" width="300"
             :src="image.url">
             </v-img>
    </v-card>
```

That is pseudo-code, i don't know or its work. Too you need a unique key,  now its now.